# SQL query change column name

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm working on some current, and archived SQLite databases.

In current versions, a column is named `message`, but in the archived versions it's named `message_id`.

The query I'm running is pretty lengthy/complex, and it's just this one column that's changed.  Is there any way I can do some kind of `CASE EXISTS` style query to do this, or am I just going to have to write a separate query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest writing a view to access the historical data:

```
create view v_message_history
    select message as message_id, . . . 
    from message_archive;
```

Then you can use the view and the two columns have the same name.

You could also use `alter table` to rename the column in either the history or current table.  I am guessing, though, that you don't want to do that because it might break existing code.